# how to find if one cell appears one time or multiple times

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to ask a sql question:

| serial_number | produced_date | date_fixed | days_since_fixed | order_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000106 | 2020-07-09 | 2021-09-17 | 432 | 10258678 |
| 1000122 | 2020-05-20 | 2021-10-05 | 497 | 10266059 |
| 1000171 | 2020-05-27 | 2021-09-06 | 457 | 10249739 |
| 1000174 | 2020-05-12 | 2020-07-28 | 56 | 10117509 |
| 1000183 | 2020-08-14 | 2020-08-20 | 6 | 10125927 |
| 1000183 | 2020-08-14 | 2020-08-22 | 8 | 10126417 |
| 1000227 | 2020-05-19 | 2021-08-26 | 457 | 10245064 |

the table looks like this and would like to check if `serial_number` is equal to its next one, since the same serial number can appear multiple times and `order_number` is not the same, which means this `serial_number` has several fixes. for the `serial_number` only appear once the new column `days_since_last_fix` is going to be `0` and if the `serial_number` show multiple times its going to be `date_fixed.next() - date_fixed`. Im not sure how to do this..
but something like this:

```
   select t1.* ,case when t1.serial_number = t2.serial_number 
   --if appear multiple times
   then datediff(t2.date_fixed,t1.date_fixed,days) 
   when t1.serial_number = t1.serial_number 
   --if appear once
   then date_diff(t1.date_fixed,t1.produced_date,days) 
   end as days_since_last_repair from table t1, table t2 
   where t1.serial_number = t2.serial_number 
   and t1.order_number != t2.order_number 
   from table t1, table t2
```

thank you

Comment: I could get the ones that appear multiple times by``` select t1.* from table t1, table t2 where t1.serial_number = t2.serial_number and t1.order_number <> t2.order_number``` but if I do case when t2.date_fixed > t1.date_fixed then date_diff(t2.date_fixed,t1.date_fixed,days) else date_diff(t1.date_fixed,t1.produced_date) end as days_different``` it creates more rows for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. What do t1 and t2 look like? if you want to look at values on the next row you can use analytic functions check [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts) doc out for some help. Alternative you could group the rows via the serial number like below.

### Single row grouped approach

```
WITH data as
((SELECT 1000106 serial_number, '2020-07-09' produced_date, '2021-09-17' date_fixed, 432 days_since_fixed, 10258678 order_number)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000122,'2020-05-20','2021-10-05',497,10266059)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000171,'2020-05-27','2021-09-06',457,10249739)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000174,'2020-05-12','2020-07-28',56,10117509)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000183,'2020-08-14','2020-08-20',6,10125927)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000183,'2020-08-14','2020-08-22',8,10126417)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000227,'2020-05-19','2021-08-26',457,10245064))

SELECT serial_number, COUNT(serial_number) as fix_count, ARRAY_AGG(order_number) as order_numbers,
CASE 
  WHEN COUNT(serial_number) > 1 THEN DATE_DIFF(MAX(DATE(date_fixed)), MIN(DATE(date_fixed)), DAY) 
  WHEN COUNT(serial_number) = 1 THEN 0
END as days_since_last_repair 

FROM data

GROUP BY serial_number
```

Results from above

| serial_number | fix_count | order_numbers | days_since_last_repair |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000106 | 1 | 10258678 | 0 |
| 1000122 | 1 | 10266059 | 0 |
| 1000171 | 1 | 10249739 | 0 |
| 1000174 | 1 | 10117509 | 0 |
| 1000183 | 2 | 10125927 | 2 |
|  |  | 10126417 |  |
| 1000227 | 1 | 10245064 | 0 |

### Analytic function approach

The below query uses the functions in the doc from above. It takes the data from the original table partitions by serial number then orders by date_fixed then looks at the previous row for the last date it was fixed replacing nulls with 0's.

```
WITH data as
((SELECT 1000106 serial_number, '2020-07-09' produced_date, '2021-09-17' date_fixed, 432 days_since_fixed, 10258678 order_number)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000122,'2020-05-20','2021-10-05',497,10266059)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000171,'2020-05-27','2021-09-06',457,10249739)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000174,'2020-05-12','2020-07-28',56,10117509)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000183,'2020-08-14','2020-08-20',6,10125927)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000183,'2020-08-14','2020-08-22',8,10126417)
UNION ALL ( SELECT 1000227,'2020-05-19','2021-08-26',457,10245064))

SELECT serial_number, produced_date, date_fixed,
IFNULL(DATE_DIFF(DATE(date_fixed), DATE(LAG (date_fixed,1) OVER ( PARTITION BY serial_number ORDER BY date_fixed )), DAY),0) as days_since_fixed
FROM data
```

Result from the above query.

| serial_number | produced_date | date_fixed | days_since_fixed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000106 | 2020-07-09 | 2021-09-17 | 0 |
| 1000122 | 2020-05-20 | 2021-10-05 | 0 |
| 1000171 | 2020-05-27 | 2021-09-06 | 0 |
| 1000174 | 2020-05-12 | 2020-07-28 | 0 |
| 1000183 | 2020-08-14 | 2020-08-20 | 0 |
| 1000183 | 2020-08-14 | 2020-08-22 | 2 |
| 1000227 | 2020-05-19 | 2021-08-26 | 0 |

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't make it clear, utimately I'd like to get the different days if a serial number appears multiple times where the order number is different.

Comment: and it says ```days_since_last_repair``` is not aggregated

Comment: @RaySyu Apologies there was a typo in the example. Try it now and let me know

Comment: Hey, thanks. I tried with `MAX()` and `MIN()` this would only work for a serial number that appears twice, but there are serial number appearing for more than twice, the time in between max and min doesn't show

Comment: Okay I added an analytic function option for you to check out. If you could detail what the original data table looks like and what you want the result to look like it might be helpful.

Comment: @ray Sui did it do what you wanted???

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.. I did it with LAG()

Comment: Cool, Glad it work for you. Maybe accept it as the answer so others see it...